LLamaindex: How to add new documents to an existing index
I´m testing a RAG system and I have this code which takes a pdf file, creates a lancedb and query it:
from llama_index.core import VectorStoreIndex, Settings, StorageContext, Document, SimpleDirectoryReader, \
    load_index_from_storage
from llama_index.vector_stores.lancedb import LanceDBVectorStore
from llama_index.embeddings.huggingface import HuggingFaceEmbedding


vector_store = LanceDBVectorStore(lancedb)
storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(vector_store=vector_store)
documents = SimpleDirectoryReader(input_files=["csr.pdf"]).load_data()
index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(
        documents, storage_context=storage_context, uri=lancedb
    )
query_engine = index.as_query_engine()
response = query_engine.query("Installation Example for CSR1000V Router")
print(response)

The code is working fine, but my question is:
How to add more documents to it???
I know I can pass multiple files here:
documents = SimpleDirectoryReader(input_files=["csr.pdf"]).load_data()

or even a full folder but I want to add documents later.
If I just write this again:
documents = SimpleDirectoryReader(input_files=["new.pdf"]).load_data()
index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(
        documents, storage_context=storage_context, uri=lancedb
    )

This will always override the previous information.
So my question is how to add more and more pdf to my lancedb???
i have tried:
documents = SimpleDirectoryReader(input_files=["new.pdf"]).load_data()

but this overrides the previous index

append keyword did the trick:
vector_store_lancedb = LanceDBVectorStore(uri=LANCEDB_URI, mode="append")


I wanted to note that I am using a Chroma Vector store and the Oscar's answer also worked for me with that type.  Note the 'mode="append"' in the vector_store declaration, below.  My updated code is:
# Load the existing index in append mode.
    db = chromadb.PersistentClient(path=chromadb_path)
    chroma_collection = db.get_collection(collection_name)
    print(f"START: Initial Chroma collection has {chroma_collection.count()} vectors.  Each vector represents one page of a document.")
    vector_store = ChromaVectorStore(chroma_collection=chroma_collection, mode="append")
    storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(vector_store=vector_store)
    index = VectorStoreIndex.from_vector_store(
        vector_store,
        show_progress=True
    )
    print("Loaded existing index from Disk")
    
    # Load all new documents from the directory
    filename_fn = lambda filename: {"file_name": filename}
    new_documents = SimpleDirectoryReader(input_dir=new_documents_dir, file_metadata=filename_fn).load_data()
    print(f"Loaded {len(new_documents)} new pages of documents from {new_documents_dir}")

    #Define our title extractor and question answering extractor.  See https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/module_guides/loading/documents_and_nodes/usage_metadata_extractor/
    #title_extractor = TitleExtractor(nodes=5)
    qa_extractor = QuestionsAnsweredExtractor(questions=2)
    
    # Create a new index with the new documents
    index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(
        new_documents,
        storage_context=storage_context,
        show_progress=True,
        transformations=[qa_extractor]
    )
    print(f"FINISH: Updated Chroma collection / index with new documents now has {chroma_collection.count()} vectors.  Each vector represents one page of a document.")
    

